# I met problems while importing library into android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I've tried to import a [library from github](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards)

I download the ZIP and unzipped it.Then I imported the library; the library's gradle seems to have a lot of errors that need to be fixed.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion project.TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)
        versionName project.VERSION_NAME
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}




signing {
    required { has("release") && gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}


uploadArchives {
    configuration = configurations.archives

    repositories.mavenDeployer {

        beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

        repository(url: sonatypeRepo) {
            authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername, password: sonatypePassword )
        }

        snapshotRepository(url: snapshotRepo) {
            authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername, password: sonatypePassword)
        }

        pom.project {
            name POM_NAME
            description POM_DESC
            packaging 'aar'
            url POM_URL

            scm {
                url POM_SCM_URL
                connection POM_SCM_CONN
                developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONN
            }

            licenses {
                license {
                    name LICENCE_NAME
                    url LICENCE_URL
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }

            developers {
                developer {
                    id POM_DEV
                    name POM_DEV_NAME
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've replaced the `SDK_VERSION` with my project's version, but there are still a lot of errors & I don't know how to fix them.

Comment: Use Gradle compile, do not use JAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly add dependency in your build.gradle, no need to download jar file and import it.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:X.X.X@aar'
}
```

They have given direct way to use it in your project, then why should you download jar file?

If you don't want aar file, they have also given a link to import maven file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
}
```

> Go ahead find the latest version on [Gradle please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#com.lorentzos.swipecards) cowboy! Be sure to
>   add the @aar suffix.

Comment: I agree with @RRR. Most official GitHub repos have created a dependency API system. Besides, there are too many complications of merging two separate android project structures. You can't have 2 gradle files..

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to stuck yourself. There is no need to put jar file.

Just add following line in **dependency** of **app level** **`build.gradle`**:

```
compile 'com.lorentzos.swipecards:library:1.0.9'
```

It will work fine.

P.S. You can check latest version [Here.](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#com.lorentzos.swipecards)